# How do I deal with a supervisor who is manipulative and hostile?

Tags: management, manager, unprofessional-behavior

I am a fairly new employee (since March 2017) in a very large organization. I am directly related to several people who have worked for the organization for some time so I had an idea of what to expect.

My supervisor is very impulsive. She will oftentimes change the rules to better fit the outcome she would like to see and then when "it" hits the fan, will throw the closest person under the bus (oftentimes me). She tells me one thing in private and then when questioned, she acts as if she never told me.

She has now said that "others have noticed my frustration and it makes her look bad". I asked for specifics and she was unable to tell me. She has began making comments about my appearance (I'm overweight) and mentioning that *I need to walk on my lunch break instead of eating*.

How could I approach this situation? She and her superior are good friends so going up the chain is not feasible. It's very much "who you know" in this organization, with very little checks and balances for those who know the right people.

Comment: You can leave, and not work for people like this in the future.

Comment: Hello @AundreaCoursey . I edited your question so other users can understand better. However, feel free to edit it again. I consider your question "What can I do?" is too broad, I rephrased it but still is quite broad. Could you narrow down what is that you want to solve or achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @GrayCygnus. This is my first time posting so I was unsure of what to include.

Comment: And this is why you get things in writing (emails are *superb* for this).

Comment: No problem, just remember to rephrase your question if you want. Also do check [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this other](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages to improve you future questions. Have a good one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote the excellent Alison Green from "Ask A Manager":

> Your boss sucks and isn't going to change

If it weren't for the dynamic your supervisor has with her boss then going over her head might have worked, unfortunately given that and the fact that she is getting into personal attacks about your weight etc I think I'd have to say you're on to a loser there and you might just have to bite the bullet and polish up the resume.

In the meantime there are a few things you can do to try and protect yourself:

**Re: the "told one thing in private which gets denied" situation**

- If you're being asked to do any work or anything in these conversations then after you have had them send a polite e-mail to your supervisor, referenceing the conversation and it's contents, ideally with a question in there which should prompt a response, it's a *little* sneaky but you can always hold back something you think of to ask during the conversation and ask it in the e-mail e.g:

> Hi [supervisor], just following up to our earlier conversation about [task X]. Are you happy if I do this using [method/resource/whatever Y]?

or

> Hi [supervisor], just following up to our earlier conversation about [task X]. As discussed I'll do this using [method/resource/whatever Y], drop me an e-mail if this is incorrect.

If you don't have any viable questions or you just feel uncomfortable with that sort of contrived behavior (I'll admit it made me feel a little "off" just typing it - I'm *way* too honest!) then you can just send something outlining the discussion and confirming a completion date/time. This is less likely to get a response but at least it's *some* kind of paper trail!

- If this isn't a case of being given work but is instead general info then it's trickier.. it's very situational but I would treat any information you had in an un-witnessed conversation to be questionable and I would avoid acting on any of it without written or e-mailed confirmation

Getting things like this at least recorded in e-mail provides *some* cover for the shifting of rules and goalposts. It's not perfect, and would be better if your supervisor's boss were more neutral but it's better than having nothing to cover you from any moments of being thrown under a bus!

Comment: In the email, you can say something like "Please let me know if any of these details are incorrect" or "I'll assume these details are correct if you don't notify me otherwise".

Comment: @Dukeling good shout, I'll update the answer.